# Number bounding box Opencv Python

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, opencv

I am trying to extract a bounding box from house numbers, this is my code, still far from the wanted result.

the issue is that, in this case, the box does not box the number

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
original = img.copy()
# Find contours, obtain bounding box, extract and save ROI
ROI_number = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
  rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
  x,y,w,h = rect
  #x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
  if 100< w < 1000 and 100< h < 1000:
    print(x, y, w, h, w*h)
  
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    #cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    ROI_number += 1
```

**original**

[image]

**boxed**

[image]

Comment: You did not mention the problem.

Comment: it looks like that the box is drawn around the shadow, i tried with another picture (without shadow) and it works correctly

Comment: Have you tried thresholding in HSV space?

Comment: not haven't, i will have a look thanks